# Error: _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID

Tags: c++

While executing code below i get error: _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID. I assume that this has something in common with adding another object to vector but i can't find out where i make a mistake. I don't add class code because previous version of this program was written without using vector and it was running fine. If it would be necessary i can translate variable names to English or explain what which variable is used for.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "CStop.h"
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
vector<CStop>Stops;

string* array= NULL;
string name,text;
int length,time,howMany,n;

cout<<"How many stops? "<<endl;
cin>>n;

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    cout<<"Type name, length , time, how many stops"<<endl;
    cin>>name>>length>>time>>howMany;
    if(howMany> 0)
    {
        cout<<"Type stops names"<<endl;
        array= new string[howMany];
        for(int i = 0; i<howMany;i++)
        {
            cin>>text;
            array[i] = text;
        }
    }
    CStops temp(name, length,time,howMany,array);
    Stops.push_back(temp);

    if(howMany> 0) delete[] array;
}

for(int i=0;i<Stops.size();i++)
{
    cout<<Stops[i].Info()<<endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Those non-English identifiers without whitespaces look confusing.

Comment: You'll get this assert from the Microsoft CRT when your program corrupts the heap.  Your code in incomprehensible, ask help from a colleague.

Comment: Run the program with the debugger. Where exactly does the assert happen?

Comment: when i enter all required values i get [Error](http://sdrv.ms/Pe69pI)

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem my rewriting class code. I added to my class support for vectors. I still don't know why when class operates on arrays i got this strange errors but when it's not everything is working. I will be grateful if anyone can tell my what this error means and how to avoid it.